# How to push a new Item to an empty array?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have an array of studets that I use by `*ngFor`,
The student list send bi the parent component,
when the studentList is empty, I want to see one row empty on the component,
This is the array:

```
 @Input() studentList: Student[] = []; //child property
```

And In The parent cmp:

```
 get studentList(): Student[] {      //parent property
      const arr: Array<Student> = new Array<Student>();
if (getStudents()){
      arr=getStudents();
}
else{
      arr.push(new Student());
      return (arr);
    }
  }
```

`getStudents()` is a Mock method that return null,
`Student` is a simple class with `idNumber` and `studentName` props
but if the arr is empty, the `*ngFor` does not show any row.

Comment: Please show you `Student` class/interface

Comment: And your `getStudents()` method too

Comment: And how can you have both a variable and a getter with the same name ?

Comment: use an ```*ngIf="studentList.length"``` and handle go to for loop or not.

Comment: I updated the question by the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to declare the Student as [];

```
get studentList(): Student[] {      //parent property
      const arr: Student[] = []
if (getStudents()){
      arr=getStudents();
}
else{
      arr.push(new Student());
      return (arr);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in this case is use

`*ngIf=studentList.length === 0` use this condition for showing empty row

`*ngIf=studentList.length > 0` use this condition when data is available.

Comment: when *ngIf=studentList.length === 0,  how can show empty row?? this is my question...

Comment: if you are using a table you can use                                                              
   `<tr class="blank_row">
            <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>`

Comment: empty row that can updateable the new student, not empty line

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
get studentList(): Student[] {
    const arr: Array<Student> = [];
    if (arr.length){
       arr = getStudents();
    }else{
      arr = [new Student()];
    }
    return arr; // return it here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this in  your html file

```
<table>
<thead>
------
</thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="student of students">
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="students.length==0">
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```